# Feedback on Using Chrome on RDS Hosts

Tags: remote-desktop, internet-explorer, google-chrome, thin-client

How well does Chrome work on RDS hosts?  I'm looking for feedback on replacing Internet Explorer 11 with Chrome in an RDS environment.

I have a system that uses Internet Explorer 11 in a terminal services environment.  There are two RDS hosts and about 50 shared thin clients. Departments are rolling out new web apps that users will need access to that only support Chrome, Edge, and Firefox. Internet Explorer's GPO polices have been great in limiting access to unauthorized sites.  Does Chrome work just as well with their templates? Does Chrome seamlessly auto update itself or do all instances need to be closed first?

Answer (score 3):

Your question is a bit subjective. Does it work well? That depends on how you need to use it. Does it work as well with their GPO templates? It depends on what you need to manage via GPO.

Chrome works as well as any other browser in RDS. Chrome's GPO's work as well as any other third party GPO's. Chrome will auto update itself unless there's an instance running.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't using User Profile Disks or some sort of other profile redirection. You need to think about the Chrome Appdata. Otherwise, every time they switch servers they will lose all of their bookmarks etc until they land back on that server